# Removing action from template class

Tags: hooks, actions, child-theme, wp-head

I'd like to replace an action in a theme with my own version in a child. In this case, the theme hooks into `wp_head` to add it's own links. My own functions.php resides in the child theme and looks like this:

```
global $SMTheme;
remove_action('wp_head', array($SMTheme, 'headtext'));
add_action('wp_head', 'custom_headtext');
```

Unfortunately, it's not working yet and I'm fairly new to this. This is how the theme adds it's action:

```
class SMTheme {
  var $options;

  function SMTheme() {
    // some unrelated code here         
    include TEMPLATEPATH."/inc/settings.php";
    $reset='';
    // if (current_user_can('administrator')) {}
    $this->getparams($settings,$reset);
    add_action('wp_head', array(&$this, 'headtext'));
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
include TEMPLATEPATH."/inc/settings.php";
```

is your problem.

> TEMPLATEPATH

is used by the parent theme

For child themes use

> STYLESHEETPATH

so your code will be

```
include STYLESHEETPATH."/inc/settings.php";
```

Alternatively you can use

```
get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/inc/settings.php'
```